# How to change language using react native localization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, react-native

I'm following [this doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization)    for implementing a language translating method in my app. 
 There is a dropdown for choosing language and I tried to console the value 
 getting from dropdown and then passing that to  `onChangeText` function. I'm 
 using two sets of languages like english and arabic but when switching the 
 language from english to arabic the language is not changing to arabic.Following is the 
 portion of code for localization.Please help me to figure out the mistake.Thank you!

**stringsoflanguages.js**

```
const strings = new LocalizedStrings({
    "English": {
        phone_number: "Phone Number",
        register: "REGISTER/LOGIN",
        plumber: "Plumber",


    },
    "Arabic": {
        phone_number: "رقم الهاتف",
        register: "التسجيل/الدخول",
        plumber: "سباك",
    }
export default strings;
```

**register.js**

```
import stringsoflanguages from './stringsoflanguages';
  const lang = [

            { value: 'English' },
            { value: 'Arabic' },

        ];
        language = lang;

 onChangeText(text) {

        console.log(text);

        stringsoflanguages.setLanguage(text);
    }
 ....
   .....

              <Dropdown
               label="Choose Language"
               data={language}
               textColor="#fff"
               selectedItemColor="#000"
              onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                    />

                <Input
                 label="Phone Number"
                placeholder={stringsoflanguages.phone_number} />

                <Button onPress={() => this.onPressRegister()}>
                <Text>{stringsoflanguages.register</Text>
                </Button>
```

Comment: The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization#examples) say you need to call `this.setState({});` after setting the language, most likely to force a re-render.

Comment: I tried that but getting error  `this.setState` is undefined

Comment: Well, you have to properly bind the function.  The easiest way is to replace `onChangeText(text) {` with `onChangeText = (text) => {` provided your environment supports that. (This is common React knowledge though and has nothing to do with the question.)

Comment: Yes it is working thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Also I've a doubt how do I pass this value to next  pages also .Do i need to pass `this.state.text` or just `text` ?

Comment: If you have a container component for your pages, then the chosen language needs to be in the state of that container so you can pass it to all pages. Which means the selection has to send it up, and your container has to pass it down. How to do that is explained all over the react docs, stack overflow and the internet in general.

Comment: Yeah I'l check.Thank you.